# A few problems with maps and location listeners - Android

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I have a few questions regarding the Google maps api and its usage etc. For a brief background on what I've done so far is that I've shown maps that are extending FragmentActivity while implementing OnMyLocationChangeListener and LocationListener. Then I've set the LocationManager and got my position from it. The map works fine. My position is also shown on the map with a blue marker and everything looks set...

1. The problem is that my position is not updated when I run the app using GPRS/EDGE. I mean it gets updated but after a very long time (2 or 3 minutes) and even then the marker is misplaced by a few hundred meters and doesn't show my exact location. Why is this problem occurring? Is my GPRS/EDGE the problem? Would it "work fast"/"show correct location" on 3G?
2. The second problem is that the OnLocationChanged(Location location) function is NEVER called. While the onMyLocationChange(Location location) is called EVERY TIME. Is this the correct behavior? Or should the OnLocationChanged(Location location) function be called as frequently as the onMyLocationChange(Location location) function?
3. The third and the most important one to be addressed is that I have placed a few markers on my map and I need to calculate the distance of each marker from my position. Now when I move, the distances between me and all the markers change, I have implemented a loop for calculating distances and saving them in an array in the onMyLocationChange(Location location) function, but it is called so quickly again and again that the for loop doesn't execute at all. Is there an alternative where I can simply call these functions after (let's say) five seconds so while inside the five seconds the for loop gets executed properly and fully and my distance array gets populated.

   ```
       FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
   SupportMapFragment mySupportMapFragment 
   = (SupportMapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
   myMap = mySupportMapFragment.getMap();

   locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

   if(locationManager != null){
       locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 
               0, 0, this);
       Location location = locationManager.
               getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

       myPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
   } 
   else {
       Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Location manager is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
       toast.show();
   }

   myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
   myMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);
   myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myPosition, 16));

    public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {

   myPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

   Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "This one is always called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
   toast.show();
      }

       @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

   myPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

   Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "This one never gets called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
   toast.show();
     }
   ```

Comment: You should post your code or at least the relevant portion of it, thanks.

Comment: Sorry. I just added the code. Check now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not posted any line of code, it's difficult to get an exact picture, but as for your question no. 3.:

You can set how often you want to get notified upon a location change, you certainly have a similar line of code, set the 2nd and the 3rd parameters of your method call to something different from 0. That should give you time to execute necessary calculations.

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationProvider, minInterval, minDistance, locationListener);
```

The Android Developers site has [an article worth reading](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) when developing location-aware apps.

Comment: I added my code. Kindly take a look at it and answer my questions plz.